# How can i run a test script at azure DevOps repository with jenkins pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework

I try to create jenkins pipeline with azure repository to run my robotframework test cases. I've been colonnig my repository with succes, but i don't know how can i run the test cases file.

I've been trying this command on my stage "Test": sh 'cd GWA_TA/'

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('azureRepo') {
            steps {
                checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'xxx']])
            }
        }
    
        stage('Test') {
            steps{
                
                sh 'cd GWA_TA/'
            }               
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont know how to run robot but you need to automate running it ?